# WCF: how to recognize pending HTTP requests

Tags: c#, wcf, request, queue

## Observed behavior (example):

When sending 100 HTTP requests to my WCF service, the WCF framework receives and dispatches only 11 requests, because my backend code limits concurrent processing to 10 requests at a time.

According to Fiddler the 12th HTTP request is actually not even received on the transport level.

I simulated a processing time of 5 seconds for each request on the server side. The 12th request is read from the network socket, once one of the previous 10 requests has been processed and processing of the 11th request has *begun*.

## Problem

I want to monitor how many requests are currently pending. Ultimately, i want to refuse new requests once the queue has exceeded a certain limit.

## Test setup

The WCF service is configured like this (PSEUDO code):

```
ServiceBehaviorAttribute.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single
ServiceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = int.MaxValue
ServiceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = int.MaxValue
ServiceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions= int.MaxValue
```

Additionally, I added a custom contract behavior to apply my own fixed-size thread pool for request processing (behavior is almost the same when using the .NET thread pool):

```
    void IContractBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(
        ContractDescription contractDescription, 
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
        DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.SynchronizationContext = SYNCHRONIZER;
    }
```

where SYNCHRONIZER is a class deriving from SynchronizationContext and overriding the "Post" method to actually enqueue the work item.

## Notes

- I tested the client: there was no problem sending 100 HTTP requests to the service concurrently. If I increase the server-side worker thread count to 100, all the requests are transmitted instantly and the overall test execution time is 5 seconds.
- The Windows performance counter "Calls outstanding" from System.ServiceModel shows the number of *dispatched* requests (so it's not useful).
- I tried to attach different performance profilers. But they did not guide me to the mysterious code location where threads were blocking request reception.

Can somebody explain the observed behavior?